# How do I determine the endianness of a NifTi file?

Tags: c++, file-format, endianness

I've a NifTi file and when I load it values are strangely scattered within scope of int_32. However, when I load the same file via NifTi-Python bindings, the value-range is different and correct. (I know that this is correct, as the producer of the file (FSL), claims only to produce values within that range.) So I want to check if the values are really stored in a different endianness (compared to other files), and if so, interpret those values correctly then.

Comment: Wouldn't a file format specification insist on an endianness as opposed to letting it be arbitrary? Hence, you'd likely want to detect the endianness of your own computer at runtime and adjust your file reading code as appropriate. You didn't share any code, so it's hard to tell what your real problem is.

Comment: The file format will either specify the endianness, or specify a means of determining it from the files contents.  (A text file might start with a BOM, for example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the first field in the `nifti_1_header` structure. It's `sizeof_hdr` and it contains the size of the header (in my case a single 348 bytes structure rather than three smaller structs).

Simply read first 4 bytes of the header, it should be `348` (alias `0x0000015C`), if it has been written in big endian you'll have `0x5C010000` (so on disk you'll read `5C 01 00 00` for little endian and `00 00 01 5C` for big endian).

Comment: Great with `hexdump -C` I could ensure that all my files have the same endianness, and showed that my bug was not related to endianness. (Instead somewhere in the code an `int32_t` variable was assigned `std::numeric_limits< double >::max()` which lead to `-214XXXXXX...` which I assume to be minimum of `int32_t`.)